# Continue Watching Section Displays All Videos Instead of Last Clicked Video - JavaScript/HTML

Tags: javascript, html, user-interface

I'm working on a web application where users can watch videos, and I have a "Continue Watching" section that should display the last clicked video. However, instead of showing only the last clicked video, it's displaying all eight videos in the "Continue Watching" space.

I've tried to implement a logic that saves the last clicked video in the lastWatchedVideos array and updates the "Continue Watching" section accordingly. Unfortunately, it seems to be loading all videos rather than just the last one.

Here's the relevant JavaScript code snippet responsible for handling video clicks and updating the "Continue Watching" section:

```js
 <script>
      let loaded = false;
      let currentPage = 1;
      const videosPerPage = 8; // Display only 4 videos
      let loadedVideos = [];
      let lastWatchedVideos = [];

      if (localStorage.getItem('lastWatchedVideos')) {
        lastWatchedVideos = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('lastWatchedVideos'));
      }

      function setDefaultInfo(videoId) {
        // Function to set default information if details are not available
        const videoTitle = document.getElementById(`video-title-${videoId}`);
        const videoDescription = document.getElementById(`video-description-${videoId}`);
        const videoThumbnail = document.getElementById(`video-thumbnail-${videoId}`);

        if (videoTitle && videoDescription && videoThumbnail) {
          videoTitle.innerText = "No Title Found";
          videoDescription.innerText = "No Description Found";

          videoThumbnail.src = `images/thumbnails/${videoId}.jpg`;
          videoThumbnail.alt = "Video Title";
          videoThumbnail.className = "video-thumbnail";

          console.log(`Default info set for video ${videoId}`);
        }
      }

      function playVideo(videoId) {
        if (!loaded) {
          const videoPlayer = document.getElementById('video-player');
          const videoTitle = document.getElementById(`video-title-${videoId}`);
          const videoDescription = document.getElementById(`video-description-${videoId}`);
          const videoThumbnail = document.getElementById(`video-thumbnail-${videoId}`);

          if (videoPlayer && videoTitle && videoDescription && videoThumbnail) {
            fetch(`details/${videoId}.json`)
              .then((response) => {
                if (!response.ok) {
                  throw new Error(`HTTP error! Status: ${response.status}`);
                }
                return response.json();
              })
              .then((data) => {
                console.log('Fetched data:', data);

                const { title, description, thumbnail, videoSrc } = data;

                if (videoSrc) {
                  videoPlayer.src = videoSrc;
                }

                videoTitle.innerText = title || 'No Title Found';
                videoDescription.innerText = description || 'No Description Found';
                videoThumbnail.src = thumbnail || `images/thumbnails/${videoId}.jpg`;

                loaded = true;
              })
              .catch((error) => {
                console.error('Error fetching video details:', error);
                setDefaultInfo(videoId);
              });
          } else {
            console.error(`One or more elements not found for video ${videoId}`);
          }
        } else {
          console.log(`Video ${videoId} clicked or loaded.`);
        }

        // Add the following lines to track the last four videos
        if (!lastWatchedVideos.includes(videoId)) {
            // Save the clicked video in user data
            lastWatchedVideos.unshift(videoId);
            if (lastWatchedVideos.length > 4) {
                lastWatchedVideos.pop();
            }

            // Save updated lastWatchedVideos to localStorage
            localStorage.setItem('lastWatchedVideos', JSON.stringify(lastWatchedVideos));
        }

        // Update the "Continue Watching" section
        updateContinueWatching();
      }
      
      function updateContinueWatching() {
          const continueWatchingSection = document.getElementById('continue-watching');
          continueWatchingSection.innerHTML = '<div id="video-player">Continue Watching:</div>';

          if (lastWatchedVideos.length === 0) {
              displayNoVideosMessage(continueWatchingSection);
              return;
          }

          const lastVideoId = lastWatchedVideos[0];

          const videoCard = document.createElement('div');
          videoCard.classList.add('video-card', 'continue-watching');
          videoCard.onclick = () => playContinueWatchingVideo(lastVideoId);

          fetchVideoDetails(lastVideoId).then((data) => {
              if (!data) {
                  displayNoVideosMessage(continueWatchingSection);
                  return;
              }

              const { title, description, thumbnail } = data;

              videoCard.innerHTML = `
                  <img src="${thumbnail || `images/thumbnails/${lastVideoId}.jpg`}" alt="Video ${lastVideoId}" class="video-thumbnail" />
                  <div class="video-details">
                      <div class="video-title">${title || 'No Title Found'}</div>
                      <div class="video-description">${description || 'No Description Found'}</div>
                  </div>
              `;

              continueWatchingSection.appendChild(videoCard);
          });
      }



      function playContinueWatchingVideo(videoId) {
        // Add specific logic for "Continue Watching" videos if needed
        // This function will be called when clicking on a "Continue Watching" video card
        playVideo(videoId);
      }

      // Function to fetch video details
      function fetchVideoDetails(videoId) {
        return fetch(`details/${videoId}.json`)
          .then((response) => {
            if (!response.ok) {
              throw new Error(`HTTP error! Status: ${response.status}`);
            }
            return response.json();
          })
          .catch((error) => {
            console.error('Error fetching video details:', error);
            return {};
          });
      }

      // Ensure that the lastWatchedVideos array is updated on page load
      window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
        if (loadedVideos.length === 0) {
          displayAllVideosMessage();
          updateContinueWatching();
        }
      });

      function loadVideos() {
        for (let i = 1; i <= videosPerPage; i++) {
          const videoIndex = (currentPage - 1) * videosPerPage + i;
          if (!loadedVideos.includes(videoIndex)) {
            playVideo(`video${videoIndex}`);
            loadedVideos.push(videoIndex);
          }
        }
      }

      function handleScroll() {
        const lastVideoCard = document.querySelector('.video-card:last-child');
        const lastCardOffset = lastVideoCard.offsetTop + lastVideoCard.clientHeight;
        const pageOffset = window.pageYOffset + window.innerHeight;

        if (pageOffset > lastCardOffset - 100 && !loaded) {
          loaded = true;
          loadVideos();
          currentPage++;
        }
      }

      function displayAllVideosMessage() {
        const videoContainer = document.getElementById('video-container');
        const message = document.createElement('p');
        message.innerText = 'All videos in our database are loaded! :p';
        videoContainer.appendChild(message);
      }

      // Check if all videos are loaded and display a message
      window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
        if (loadedVideos.length === 0) {
          displayAllVideosMessage();
        }
      });

      function toggleSideMenu() {
        const sideMenuOverlay = document.getElementById('side-menu-overlay');
        const sideMenu = document.getElementById('side-menu');

        if (sideMenuOverlay.style.display === 'block' || sideMenu.style.display === 'block') {
          sideMenuOverlay.style.display = 'none';
          sideMenu.style.display = 'none';
        } else {
          sideMenuOverlay.style.display = 'block';
          sideMenu.style.display = 'block';
        }
      }

      function closeSideMenu() {
        const sideMenuOverlay = document.getElementById('side-menu-overlay');
        const sideMenu = document.getElementById('side-menu');

        sideMenuOverlay.style.display = 'none';
        sideMenu.style.display = 'none';
      }

      function displayNoVideosMessage(continueWatchingSection) {
        const message = document.createElement('p');
        message.innerText = 'No videos found!';
        continueWatchingSection.appendChild(message);
      }

      // Initial load of videos
      loadVideos();

      // Add scroll event listener
      window.addEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);
    </script>
```

I've also included the main structure of the HTML and JavaScript code, but the issue seems to be in the logic for updating the "Continue Watching" section.

Any help or suggestions on how to fix this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!